# How to write automated functional test using Facebook SDK in Android app?

Tags: android, facebook, android-testing, android-espresso

I need to write an automated test of my Android app that is using Facebook login. 
Does anyone know how to write test of the Facebook login? I'm using Espresso to automate the UI test.

Comment: is it problem solved